# Is there a "How do they do that?" site for learning image post-processing techniques by examples?

Tags: post-processing, web

I often see really excellent photographs that seem to have been adjusted in photoshop or something like that. This includes even pictures that seem to be from someone's vacation or travel.

Is there a site where they show a great photo (lets say daily) and an explanation of how the effect was achieved? I want to learn by seeing a photo I love and then seeing how it was made.

Comment: Not directly answering your question, but on Sept. 20th, creativeLIVE are about to broadcast a comprehensive free 4-day Photoshop CS5 workshop with Lesa Snider: http://www.creativelive.com/courses/photoshop-cs5-lesa-snider

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Post processing in Photoshop (and similar tools) are one of the benefits of digital photography. With quite simple means you can edit the files from your camera, improving the final product. For some it's almost as important as taking the actual shot.

There are many ways to learn "photoshopping" (or *retouching*). I cannot direct you to a particular web site but I know many books covering this subject. There are books on portrait retouching, HDR and of cause general editing in Photoshop.

Scott Kelby is the number one selling author in the field of photography. You can browse through his collection of books (and books from some of his colleges/friends) on [Kelby Training Books](http://www.kelbytraining.com/books/).

Of course there are web sites too, but if you would like to learn the art of photo editing I would recommend a book.

Answer (score 3):

There isn't a site like that that I know of, but you can always post an image you like here (rights permitting) and more often than not someone will be able to help you. Bear in mind that not every shot has achieved an effect purely through Photoshop though; lighting is a major factor.

Comment: Lighting and camera settings in general.